# Use golang template to print list separated with comma and "or"

Tags: templates, go

It is already elsewhere discussed on stackoverflow that you can print a list separated by comma, as follows:

```
{{ range $index, $element := .TeamMembers}}
    {{if $index}},{{end}}
    {{$element.Name}}
{{end}}
```

Is there an easy solution for when you need a list separator that is different for the last item, to include an "or":

```
{name}, {name}, {name}, or {name}
```

This is to allow, for example, creation of formatted sentences such as:

```
The members of this team are Bob, Jane, and Mike.
```

Any template code I can workout ends up extremely verbose and complicated.

Comment: Have you considered moving the logic out of the template and exposing it via a string property?

Comment: Just in case you want to take a look on other template engines for Go; I just put up an example on how you could do this task in pongo2: https://www.florian-schlachter.de/pongo2/?id=2077036808

Comment: @SimonWhitehead This is certainly an option. However I would prefer to not to have to write code to handle "view/presentation" code to deal with limitations of the template library if possible.

Comment: Seems like you could write a function to do the joining and add it via [`Funcs()`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs)--I've something similar to generate lists like this in other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Export a function to your template](http://play.golang.org/p/QMy-pkj2N8).

`text/template`, like some other template systems, doesn't try be good for programming in directly; it just provides a better way to stitch your data and functions with your markup, and you need to write other presentational code when it's insufficient. You can write a `yourapp/template` module that exports a version of `New()` that calls `Funcs()` to add the common functions you use.

(You might find uses for a lot more functions than just these; Django, for example, offers [lots of builtins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/) for pluralization, formatting, i18n, etc., and folks still often extend the set.)

```
package main // package mytemplate

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
)

func conjoin(conj string, items []string) string {
    if len(items) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    if len(items) == 1 {
        return items[0]
    }
    if len(items) == 2 { // "a and b" not "a, and b"
        return items[0] + " " + conj + " " + items[1]
    }

    sep := ", "
    pieces := []string{items[0]}
    for _, item := range items[1 : len(items)-1] {
        pieces = append(pieces, sep, item)
    }
    pieces = append(pieces, sep, conj, " ", items[len(items)-1])

    return strings.Join(pieces, "")
}

// if you use some funcs everywhere have some package export a Template constructor that makes them available, like this:

var commonFuncs = template.FuncMap{
    "andlist": func(items []string) string { return conjoin("and", items) },
    "orlist":  func(items []string) string { return conjoin("or", items) },
}

func New(name string) *template.Template {
    return template.New(name).Funcs(commonFuncs)
}

func main() {
    // test conjoin
    fmt.Println(conjoin("or", []string{}))
    fmt.Println(conjoin("or", []string{"Bob"}))
    fmt.Println(conjoin("or", []string{"Bob", "Mike"}))
    fmt.Println(conjoin("or", []string{"Bob", "Mike", "Harold"}))

    people := []string{"Bob", "Mike", "Harold", "Academy Award nominee William H. Macy"}
    data := map[string]interface{}{"people": people}
    tmpl, err := New("myyy template").Parse("{{ orlist .people }} / {{ andlist .people }}")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("sadness:", err.Error())
        return
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("sadness:", err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

[Here's a variation](http://play.golang.org/p/MWpr9mlTdC) that also exports "conjoin", and an "isLast" function you can use in a kind of verbose construction to do some arbitrary thing differently in the last go through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

For the "creation of a proper English formatted sentence" from a list use a function.

Your plural example is

```
The members of this team are Bob, Jane, and Mike.
```

What is your singular example where there is only one element in the list? For example,

```
The only member of this team is Bob.
```

What is your empty example when there are no elements in the list? For example,

```
There are no members of this team.
```

Creating proper English sentences and paragraphs from a mail merge is hard.

Comment: Please don't get hung up on the english bit. My question is about how to generate a comma separated list where the last item has an "or".

Comment: I think he answered the question, though. Use a function.